# mongodb $regex and $in combined using pymongo, is it possible?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to pass in a list to regex, as follows. I cannot find an evidence to see how to cojoin `$in` and `$regex`

```
query = {"platform": {"$regex": {"$in": [platform_list]}, "$options":"i"}, "$or": []}
result = mongo.db.xxx.find(query)
```

I get the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $regex has to be a string
```

How should I format the string, so that I can apply my query to each item in `platform_list`

Comment: Could you provide example documents and which should be matched? Thanks.